# JQuery DataTables is not showing Data in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u147Q0NY6Qg&index=2&t=0s&list=PLjC4UKOOcfDQl-5j8RIWoODQf34ofmc0Y) tutorial to learn and understand about jquery datatables.

But, i am not getting any data in the browser. Tried 3 times before posting this question in stackoverflow.

Can anyone please tell where I am doing wrong?

Below is my Index.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_DataTablesLayout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<table id="customersTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Customer ID</th>
            <th>Company Name</th>
            <th>Contact Name</th>
            <th>Contact Title</th>
            <th>Address</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
@section scripts {

}
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#customersTable").DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": "DataTables/GetList",
                "type": "GET",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "CustomerID" },
                { "data": "CompanyName" },
                { "data": "ContactName" },
                { "data": "ContactTitle" },
                { "data": "Address" }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Below is the Layout page:_DataTablesLayout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="~/Content/DataTables/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @RenderBody()
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the code in `DataTablesController`

```
public class DataTablesController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult GetList()
    {
        NorthwindEntities db = new NorthwindEntities();
        var customersList = db.Customers.Select(x => new {
            x.CustomerID,
            x.CompanyName,
            x.ContactName,
            x.ContactTitle,
            x.Address
        }).ToList();
        return Json(new { data = customersList }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

I am getting just blank screen. I didn't get JavaScrip errors as well when verified using F12 Developer tools in Internet Explorer.

Comment: Why are you using ajax instead of passing the model to the view?

Comment: @StephenMuecke: This is how i learned while watching the video. Is there any better way? Please suggest me. If possible, please give solution.

Comment: What you doing currently is making 2 requests (one to return a view containing just the table headings, and then another to get the data for the table) wasting time and resources. Your Index at method should return the model - i.e. `IEnumerable<Customer> model = db.Customers; return View(model)` and in the view you have `@model IEnumerable<Customer>` and  a `foreach` loop to generate the table rows (then the script is just `$("#customersTable").DataTable();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code whatever I posted as a question is perfectly alright. I verified the output in Internet Explorer, hence it is not working.

After discussion with office colleague, came to know that my code is perfectly working in all the browsers including Fire Fox, Opera, Chrome, Edge. The above code is not working only in Internet Explorer.

Not sure what changes are required to make the code work in Internet Explorer.